# Disappearing values from 2D integer array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

Edited question:

In class GameSetting I declared the 2D array private int[][] gameArray = new int[3][3];
Inside this class created public void setValue(int i, int j, int value);
and one getter for gameArray.

```
public class GameSetting {

private int[][] gameArray;

public GameSetting(){
    gameArray = new int[3][3];
}

public void setValue(int i, int j, int value){
    this.gameArray[i][j] = value;
}

public int[][] getGameArray(){
    return this.gameArray;
}
```

}

When I'm creating an instance of class GameSetting setting = new Setting();
and using for example:

> setting.setValue(0,2,2);
> setting.setValue(1,2,1);
> setting.setValue(0,0,2);

at the end all values inside gameArray are null except the last one. (In this case setting.setValue(0,0,2);)

I need to save all values inside myArray.

Could anyone help fix this problem?

Below is the class where I call method:

setValue(int i, int j, int value);

---

```
public class MyButton extends Button
```

{

```
private int x;
private int y;
private int k;
private int g;
private int coordinateA;
private int coordinateB;
private GameSetting gameSettings = new GameSetting();



public MyButton(String name, int x, int y, int k, int g, int coordinateA, int coordinateB)
{
    super(name);
    this.setLayoutX(x);
    this.setLayoutY(y);
    this.setPrefHeight(121);
    this.setPrefWidth(121);
    this.setOpacity(0.5);
    this.setCursor(Cursor.CLOSED_HAND);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.k = k;
    this.g = g;
    this.coordinateA = coordinateA;
    this.coordinateB = coordinateB;
}
public void clickToPlay()
{
    this.setOnAction(event -> {
        Parent parent = this.getParent();

        if(parent instanceof Group){

            ((Group) parent).getChildren().remove(this);

            if(HelloApplication.whichPlayer%2 == 0) {

                GameImage imageViewCross = new GameImage(HelloApplication.circle, this.k, this.g);

                gameSettings.setValue(coordinateA, coordinateB, 1);//Method setValue


                ((Group) parent).getChildren().add(imageViewCross);
            }else{
                GameImage imageViewCircle = new GameImage(HelloApplication.cross, this.k, this.g);

                gameSettings.setValue(coordinateA, coordinateB, 2); //Method setValue

                ((Group) parent).getChildren().add(imageViewCircle);
            }
            HelloApplication.whichPlayer++;
            if(HelloApplication.whichPlayer == 9){
                int[][] test = gameSettings.getGameArray();

                for (final int[] is : test) {
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(is));
                }
            }
        }

    });
}
```

}

Comment: Cannot reproduce. After Creating an Object of `MySetting` and doing all the `setValue` calls you describe The Objects array ends up being: `[[2, 0, 2], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0]]` just as expected. Whatever problem it is you are experiencing has nothing to do with the code you posted and nothing to do with disappearing array values. See code demonstrated here:  https://ideone.com/l1c7os

Comment: Please show your code of how u read values from array.

Comment: From the code for `MyButton` that you posted (as answer) it seems that **every** `MyButton` instance has its own private `GameSettings gameSettings` object. If you modify the `gameSettings` of one `MyButton` it does not influence the (independent) `gameSettings` of another button - and maybe you even have one more independent `GameSettings` instance in your main class.

Comment: @ThomasKläger - you are right! But what should I do with GameSettings? Should I create the global instance of GameSettings class?